# Is there a difference between a Kotlin suspend function being in a state of waiting and being in a state of suspended?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

To illustrate, the [docs](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/delay.html) for the suspend function `delay` says:

> Delays coroutine for a given time without blocking a thread and resumes it after a specified time.
> This suspending function is cancellable. If the Job of the current coroutine is cancelled or completed while this suspending function is *waiting*, this function immediately resumes with CancellationException. There is a prompt cancellation guarantee. If the job was cancelled while this function was *suspended*, it will not resume successfully.

In this description, do *waiting* and *suspended* mean the same thing?  Or is a suspend function that is *waiting* in a different type of state from when it's *suspended*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no specific meaning for "waiting" in this case (to my knowledge), I would say it could definitely be read as "suspended". Both parts of this doc refer to the same state.